# array into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, firebase

So I am trying to populate a single object. My data looks like this right now:

```
[ { 'id1': 
     { name: 'K Mmm',
       time: '1583308800/1583395199',
       ref: 'JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo/JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo' } },
  { 'id2': 
     { name: 'Bb Bb',
       time: '1583125200/1583222399',
       ref: 'JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo/JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo' } } ]
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
{'id1': 
     { name: 'K Mmm',
       time: '1583308800/1583395199',
       ref: 'JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo/JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo' } ,
 'id2': 
     { name: 'Bb Bb',
       time: '1583125200/1583222399',
       ref: 'JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo/JK92fYxGmCofsWa1DMDMKXSo' } ,
... }
```

The problem is that I am getting a object in a `for` loop, is there any way to populate an object from scratch?
Right not I am pushing to Array with .push().
Like push but to a  object instead to an array?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: if you were to store the array in a variable `dataArr` you could create a object `dataObj` by using the following code; 
`var dataObj = {}; for(var e in dataArr) dataObj[Object.keys(dataArr[e])] = dataArr[e][Object.keys(dataArr[e])];`
it is kind of cheating but it does the job

Comment: For some reason the Solution there doesnt work for me, I already tried this answer.. I am using es7